# Who gets the yellow trikot at a time draw - Tour de France

Tags: cycling

Yesterday was the team time trial at the Tour de France. Team Jumbo - Visma, the team with the yellow jersey, won and the yellow stayed in their team. But it got me thinking: What would have happened if, let's say Team Ineos would have won, who would have gotten the yellow jersey, since they all had the same time after the first day.
Would the one who drove over the finish line first or the first one in the alphabet get the yellow jersey? What is the rule in this situation?

Comment: This seems related: [What is used as tie-breaker for cyclists with the same time in GC?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/8896)

Comment: In this case, they would have looked at the race on day 1 and looked at what time everyone finished the race?

Comment: And did they look at the team time trial too? Since there the individual time does not really matter...

Comment: Some parts of the Wikipedia article [Team time trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_time_trial) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Team_time_trial&oldid=905310799)) might also be relevant: "Where a TTT is part of a stage race, it is necessary for each rider to be given a finish time that can be cumulated into the general classification timings. Hence, all riders in the team who finish in the leading bunch are given the time of the fourth rider, and any rider who has been dropped is timed individually in the usual way."

Comment: On Tour de France, it is fifth rather than fourth rider. The same Wikipedia article also mentions: "If a stage race starts with team time trial, the leader's jersey is given to a rider who finishes first of the winning team."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, the first rider of team Ineos to cross the line would be the GC leader. It happens very often when a stage contest starts with a Team Time Trial.